# Pypy (python) optimization

Tags: python, bubble-sort, pypy

I'm looking into replacing some C code with python code and using pypy as the interpreter. The code does a lot of list/dictionary operations. Therefore to get a vague idea of the performance of pypy vs C I am writing sorting algorithms. To test all my read functions I wrote a bubble sort, both in python and C++. CPython of course sucks 6.468s, pypy came in at 0.366s and C++ at 0.229s. Then I remembered that I had forgotten -O3 on the C++ code and the time went to 0.042s. For a 32768 dataset C++ with -O3 is only 2.588s and pypy is 19.65s. Is there anything I can do to speed up my python code (besides using a better sort algorithm of course) or how I use pypy (some flag or something)?

Python code (read_nums module omitted since it's time is trivial: 0.036s on 32768 dataset):

```
import read_nums
import sys

nums = read_nums.read_nums(sys.argv[1])

done = False

while not done:
    done = True

    for i in range(len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i] > nums[i+1]:
            nums[i], nums[i+1] = nums[i+1], nums[i]
            done = False

$ time pypy-c2.0 bubble_sort.py test_32768_1.nums   
real    0m20.199s
user    0m20.189s
sys     0m0.009s
```

C code (read_nums function again omitted since it takes little time: 0.017s):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "read_nums.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<int> nums;
    int count, i, tmp;
    bool done;

    if(argc < 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " filename" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    count = read_nums(argv[1], nums);

    done = false;

    while(!done)
    {
        done = true;

        for(i=0; i<count-1; ++i)
        {
            if(nums[i] > nums[i+1])
            {
                tmp = nums[i];
                nums[i] = nums[i+1];
                nums[i+1] = tmp;
                done = false;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<count; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << nums[i] << ", ";
    }

    return 0;
}

$ time ./bubble_sort test_32768_1.nums > /dev/null  
real    0m2.587s
user    0m2.586s
sys     0m0.001s
```

**P.S.** Some of the numbers given in the first paragraph are a little different then the numbers from time because they're the numbers I got the first time.

**Further improvements:**

- Just tried xrange instead of range and the run time went to 16.370s.
- Moved the code starting from first `done = False` to last `done = False` in a function, speed is now 8.771-8.834s.

Comment: What happens if you use a tmp variable like you did in the c code?

Comment: W/ xrange it takes 19.431s, w/ xrange and tmp it takes 19.760s. Not sure why my xrange just regressed so much.

Comment: Ok, the xrange no tmp was apparently an outlier, I ran it 5 more times and it ranged 16.385s-17.158s. With the tmp variable 5 times it ranged from 18.923s-19.444s.

Comment: a better question might be, why do you want to move some code from C to python? are you having trouble w/ interfacing between the two? generally people write in python, then use C when they need speed. i haven't heard of going from C to python especially when speed is an issue.

Comment: I should clarify that I am not just planning on turning C code into python code, but rather adding on a lot of code after making that transition. The C code is very hard to understand and I'm not convinced that its list/dictionary data-structures are all that efficient. Also, there is a lot of development to be done and I think the development would be easier and faster in python as opposed to C. If I could get pypy within say 20-30% of the speed of C then I would be okay with just leaving the code in python.

Answer (score 3):

The most relevant way to answer this question is to note that the speed of C, CPython and PyPy are not differing by a constant factor: it depends most importantly on what is done and the way it is written.  For example, if your C code is doing naive things like walking arrays when the "equivalent" Python code would naturally use dictionaries, then any implementation of Python is faster than C provided the arrays are long enough.  Of course, this is not the case on most real-life examples, but the same argument still applies to a smaller extent.  There is no one-size-fits-all way to predict the relative speed of a program written in C, or rewritten in Python and running on CPython or PyPy.

Obviously there are guidelines about these relative speeds: on small algorithmical examples you could expect the speed of PyPy to be approaching that of "gcc -O0".  In your example it is "only" 1.6x slower.  We might help you optimize it, or even find optimizations missing in PyPy, in order to gain 10% or 30% more speed.  But this is a tiny example that has nothing to do with your real program.  For the reasons above the speed we get here is only vaguely related to the speed you'll get in the end.

I can only say that rewriting code from C to Python for reasons of clarity, notably when the C has become too tangled up for further developments, is clearly a win in the long run --- even in the case where at the end you need to rewrite some parts of it in C again.  And PyPy's goal here is to reduce the need for that.  While it would be nice to say that no-one ever needs C any more, it's just not true `:-)`

Comment: Two things: one, I would like to learn techniques for optimizing PyPy (such as the use functions instead of doing stuff globally), two, obviously I should use the proper data-structure in C, but for instance, PyPy's implementation of a dictionary may be very good, and to get similar speed it might take a lot of effort in C in which case PyPy would have an edge.